Как включить опцию "Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту"?
Как в Gmail включить опцию "Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту"? Есть способы для выключения этой функции?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/14012355?hl=ru&sjid=2996675437313848536-EU
